# Where to put method that returns a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a **Shop** model.

In my class, I have created several methods, that allow me to make my code easier to read.

Things like :

```
# Returns True if the shop has an owner
def is_claimed
  return self.owner_id != nil
end
```

Now I want to create a method that would return a collection of Shops.

Something like :

```
def get_all_open
  return Shop.where("shops.closed != 1")
end
```

I am simply wondering where I should place it, so it is available from anywhere where I can potentially use

```
Shop.all
```

in my code.

- If I place it in the Model, it will be available to instances of shops, which would sound weird.
- This method also belongs to **Shop**, so I don't really like placing it in the **ApplicationController**.
- I also thought about placing it in the shops_controller, but then it won't be available easily to other controllers.

I have looked on the internet, but failed to find something I like so far. What would be considered a good practice in rails ?

Thanks

Comment: Or am I actually defining helper methods in my question ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html . Sounds like it.

Comment: Inside the `Shop` model `def self.all_shops; self.all;end` wouldn't be good ? It is totally makes sense here. And you can call it any where like `Shop.all_shops`...

Comment: It's definitely a good candidate for  *class method*, as Arup is suggesting: `def self.get_all_open ...`. Invoked via, `Shop.get_all_open`. Or, make it a *scope*: `scope :all_open ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep it in the Model, but instead of defining it as an instance method, define it as a class method:

```
def self.all_open
  where("shops.closed != 1")
end
```

This way you can use it like this:

```
Shop.all_open
```

And even nest methods, like this:

```
Shop.all_open.where(field: "value")
```

**UPDATE:**

Like others pointed out, you could also use scopes (this is the preferred way):

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :all_open, -> { where("shops.closed != 1") }
end
```

The usage would be the same:

```
Shop.all_open
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Coming from Java, I have some trouble transforming my concepts into the ruby notation. :)

Comment: scopes is definitely  the standard rails convention here... the only nitpick I would add is that `all_open` could be shortened to `open`  (unless there is confusion with using that as a verb)

Answer (score 2):

This is what [Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) are usually used for.

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :open, ->{ where("shops.closed != 1") }
  #            ->{ where.not(closed: true) } # <- Either will work, but I prefer this

  # ...
end
```

Then:

```
Shop.open.all # => (a collection of Shops)
```

The advantage of scopes is that you can chain them, so, for example, if your Shop model had a `type` attribute, you could get all open Shops with a certain `type` like so:

```
Shop.open.where(type: "pharmacy").all
```

Comment: I didn't know, I can call `#all` on the _scope_ .. :D

Comment: In fact, you often don't need to call `all` ...  many enumerable type methods are already defined on the resulting scope.   `Shop.open.each{|s| puts s}`

Comment: `all` is actualy unecessary in this case (in Rails 4). `Shop.open` and `Shop.open.all` will return exactly the same thing. `all` now returns a relation, and you should use `to_a` if you want an array—like for caching.

Comment: Yes, you're both correct. I included `all` in the code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a class method in Shop.

```
class Shop
  def self.all_open
    where("shops.closed != 1")
  end
end

open_shops = Shop.all_open
```

Note:

0) The `self` in `def self.all_open` is what makes this a class method, defined on the class Shop itself, and callable on the class itself as `Shop.all_open`, instead of an ordinary instance method which needs to be called on a particular instance.

1) Calling the method `all_open` instead of `get_all_open` leads to more natural and idiomatic code when you call `Shop.all_open`. I might in fact just call it `open`, leading to `open_shops = Shop.open`.

2) Note the suggested implementation omits the `return`, just for readability.  Note it also omits the `Shop.where`, and just does `where`.  This mostly only matters if you end up making sub-classes of Shop, which you probably won't, but is good style, and shorter code.  Just `where` is the same as `self.where`, and since this is a class method, `self` is the class itself, `Shop` (unless you have sub-classes inheriting this code, in which case `self` could be a sub-class).

3) You can in fact chain this with toher stuff, no problem. Check it out: `Shop.all_open.where(:city => "Baltimore").order(:updated_at)`. Pretty neat, it just works!

4) Some people will tell you to use ActiveRecord 'scopes' for this. You don't really need to for this case, you can just write a plain old method, just like that. The [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) acknowledge this about using a scope for this sort of thing:  "This is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference."  I'd just use a plain old method here, just like you started out with (except defined as a class method on the model) --  it's more straightforward, it does what you expect, you don't need to learn about 'scopes', it's just a method.  Using a scope to do this instead is kind of leftover from before Rails supported using an ordinary class method in this way, an ordinary class method is just fine.

Comment: The main reason to use scopes is that their purpose is implicit. If I'm reading a colleague's code and I see `scope`, I know that, unless my colleague has done something weird, it's going to return an ActiveRecord::Relation and I can chain it with other scopes and finder methods. If the model has a bunch of scope-like class methods mixed in with its other class methods, it makes them harder to find. You're correct that `scope` is just a convention, but like most of Rails' other conventions, it's a very useful one.

Comment: I don't agree, I prefer an ordinary method so you don't need to figure out (or debug) anything about scopes -- it's just ruby, who needs Rails magic when it doesn't add anything. You can document intent in a comment if it's needed. But everyone can have their preference!